# Using font-awesome with Phonegap on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build, font-awesome-4

I am currently developing a Phonegap app and I cannot get any fontawesome icons to show up on the device.

They show up in testing on my desktop but once I go to the device, there are no icons. They don't show up as the squares either, just nothing at all. I am including the fontawesome.css file in my index.css file, is there something more I have to do for Phonegap and fontawesome?

Comment: I don't know what Phonegap is, but does it really relieve you of the responsibility to include your font in the app bundle?

Comment: I guess I don't really know. I'm not sure how to include the font in my bundle.

Comment: Let me put it this way: how are you expecting the font to work? Does Phonegap magically do something that would make the font work (like get it off the Internet when your app runs)? If not, you would have to include the font in your bundle like everyone else.

Comment: tommy.bonderenka you are getting the correct answer from @matt  You need to include the fonts on the mobile device. DO NOT fetch them from the internet. This is not good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the font file in your app bundle, as shown in this screen shot:

[image]

Drag the font file into the Project Navigator on the left, and then edit your *Info.plist* to give the name of the font file. You will then be able to refer to the font in your app's code.

Comment: Great, thank you! Shows my lack of understanding of how native development works, even with Phonegap.